# When is it necessary to check for dependencies on each build?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I found the following tip to speed up gradle build times, but I'm not sure when or if I will need to uncheck the work offline box.  Could someone provide any scenario(s) where I will need to uncheck the work offline box?

```
You can toggle Gradle to work in offline mode so it does not look for dependencies on every build

File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle

Then look for the checkbox Offline work and enable it.
```